# Python 3.5 csv parsing with special characters

Tags: python, parsing, csv, character

I have a file that I'd like to parse into a csv.  The file is an export file, and arrives to me in the following format (line by line, each file containing thousands of lines):

```
03:30:30  08:30:30 [15 August 2015] productid:123456789 manuf:987654321 case:12 pallet:1234 id:12 code:1234  12345  123  12
```

I'd like to get the data into a csv file as follows:

```
local time, GMT time, date, product id, manuf id, case, pallet, id, code, company id, location, secondary code
03:30:30, 08:30:30, 15 August 2015, 123456789, 987654321, 12, 1234, 12, 1234, 12345, 123, 12
```

I've successfully done this, but using the wrong tools I believe.  I've been using lines like below:

```
import fileinput
for line in fileinput.FileInput("file",inplace=1):
    line = line.replace(":",",")

import fileinput
for line in fileinput.FileInput("file",inplace=1):
    line = line.replace("case"," ")
```

which gives me something like..

```
l h, l min, ls, gmt h, gmt m, gmt s, date, product id, manuf id, case, pallet, id, code, company id, location, secondary code
03,30,30,08,30,30,15 August 2015, 123456789, 987654321, 12, 1234, 12, 1234, 12345, 123, 12
```

The problems are: I have to use successive lines to parse each character and word into csv (descriptor words, colons, brackets, etc..) and it takes a long time over a large data-set.  Also I'm saving it all to a secondary file instead of writing in place.  By replacing the colons with commas, my times get broken down into separate columns.  I've spent a few days playing with different options and arrived at regex, but as a complete newb to python have yet to come up with a solution.  It may be simpler to rebuild the times from comma separated blocks into the correct format, but I'm at a loss. Please assist.  Thanks in advance.

Edit:

I've tried to implement Sparkeandshine as well as Julian's versions of a workable solution.  I came closest to getting Sparkeandshie's version to work, but am only able to iterate one line; the one actually in the solution, not the entire file.  I spent the last 24 trying different iterations of both solutions, to no avail.  Here is where I am:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import csv
import os

inputFileName = 'test.txt'
outputFileName = 'finished.csv'

with open(inputFileName, newline='') as inFile, open(outputFileName,    'w', newline='') as outfile:
    r = csv.reader(inFile)
    w = csv.writer(outfile)

    line = '03:30:30 08:30:30 [15 August 2015] productid:123456789 manuf:987654321 case:12 pallet:1234 id:12 code:1234 12345 123 12'
str_list = line.split()

new_list = [str_list[0],
        str_list[1],
        ' '.join([item.strip('[]') for item in str_list[2:5]]), # '[15', 'August', '2015]'
        str_list[6].split(':')[1],
        str_list[7].split(':')[1],
        str_list[8].split(':')[1],
        str_list[9].split(':')[1],
        str_list[10].split(':')[1],
        str_list[12],
        str_list[13]
        ]

with open(inputFileName, newline='') as inFile, open(outputFileName, 'w', newline='') as outfile:
    r = csv.reader(inFile)
    w = csv.writer(outfile)

    for row in r:
        w.writerow(new_list)
```

Edit: Sparkandshines below solution works great for set lines, but I have found that some of my data has lines of varying lengths.  For example, sometimes a few lines will be short a few "columns" of data, or the last three columns may repeat twice.  To get around this problem I have been using "try" and "except error, continue" for the possible lengths.  With this method I get duplicate lines in my final file; is there a better way to use Sparkandshine's solution with lines of varying length? ...or is it easier to just find duplicate lines (by checking / comparing two/three columns) and removing them?

Comment: what do you mean by "the file is an export file"?

Comment: have you tried the csv module? https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html?highlight=csv#module-csv

Comment: iulian, the file is exported from proprietary software and I can't alter how it is given to me.  I need to be able to normalize the data so it can be used by my office.  eugecm, I have tried, unsuccessfully, the csv module.

Comment: You don't want your csv delimited with ", ", just use ",".

Comment: @james, your input file is not in csv. Why do you use `csv.reader`?

Comment: @james, U should loop over all lines for your input file. Check my edited answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Process each line using,

```
line = '03:30:30 08:30:30 [15 August 2015] productid:123456789 manuf:987654321 case:12 pallet:1234 id:12 code:1234 12345 123 12'
str_list = line.split()

new_list = [str_list[0],
            str_list[1],
            ' '.join([item.strip('[]') for item in str_list[2:5]]), # '[15', 'August', '2015]'
            str_list[6].split(':')[1],
            str_list[7].split(':')[1],
            str_list[8].split(':')[1],
            str_list[9].split(':')[1],
            str_list[10].split(':')[1],
            str_list[12],
            str_list[13]
            ]

print(new_list)
# Output
['03:30:30', '08:30:30', '15 August 2015', '987654321', '12', '1234', '12', '1234', '123', '12']
```

Write to a csv file with,

```
with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)

    # write the file header
    fieldnames = ['local time', 'GMT time', 'date', 'product id', 'manuf id', 
            'case', 'pallet', 'id', 'code', 'company id', 'location', 'secondary code']
    writer.writerow(fieldnames)

    # process each line
    for line in lines:
        new_list = do_something()

        writer.writerow(new_list) # write to the file
```

Or process all lines and save the results to a list of lists, then wirte to a csv file with `writerows`,

```
writer.writerows(lists)
```

---

The full source code,

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import csv

inputFileName = 'test.txt'
outputFileName = 'finished.csv'

with open(outputFileName, 'w') as outfile:
    w = csv.writer(outfile)

    # write the file header
    fieldnames = ['local time', 'GMT time', 'date', 'product id', 'manuf id', 
            'case', 'pallet', 'id', 'code', 'company id', 'location', 'secondary code']
    writer.writerow(fieldnames)


    # process each line
    with open(inputFileName, 'r') as inFile:
        for line in inFile:
            str_list = line.rstrip().split()
            new_list = [str_list[0],
                        str_list[1],
                        ' '.join([item.strip('[]') for item in str_list[2:5]]), # '[15', 'August', '2015]'
                        str_list[6].split(':')[1],
                        str_list[7].split(':')[1],
                        str_list[8].split(':')[1],
                        str_list[9].split(':')[1],
                        str_list[10].split(':')[1],
                        str_list[12],
                        str_list[13]]

            w.writerow(new_list) # write to the file
```

Comment: Eureka!  Really appreciate the help.  The bit with the fieldnames for the file header still does not iterate, but no worries, I know how to inject a header row after this function to make that happen.  Really appreciate your quick responses and guidance on solving this problem for me.   I spent DAYS searching on the internet trying to solve this problem or learn the solution; I will be using this method a lot for other similar scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a known structure of your input files, you don't need to use regular expressions, as they are slower. For your case, try using something similar to the code below:

```
import csv
with open('destination.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    ...  # get your data here, the next code is for one line of data
    values = line.split()
    values[2] = '{} {} {}'.format(values[2][1:], values[3], values[4][:-1])  # Get rid of square brackets
    for idx in range(5, 11):
        values[idx] = values[idx].split(':')[1]  # get the number values
    values.pop(3);  # remove separated month name
    values.pop(3);  # remove separated year

    csv_writer.writerow(values)
```

You are editing only the data that requires it and then write the whole row to the csv.

Comment: `line.split()` splits `[15 August 2015]` as `'[15', 'August', '2015]'` (3 elements of `values`). So, `values[2] = values[2][1:-1]` returns `1`.

Comment: @sparkandshine my bad, wasn't very attentive. fixed it now